# Texture invisible

Tags: texturing

I have created a new texture and assigned an image to it.

I have checked the UV mapping, and it looks fine to me.
However, when I render using Shift + Z, the body renders invisibly.

Does anybody see what I might have done wrong?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Here is the node. I hope I have captured the right settings.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the alpha channel in your image is 0, or somehow you are plugging in an alpha value of 0 for your character's skin. We need to see the nodes to know for sure what is going on.

Comment: @beiller I have added a screenshot of the nodes. Is that what you meant?